# Best way to store videos and images in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, video

Hi I'm creating a webapp and I want to be able to upload videos and images from the app GUI instead of going through the console. I've heard that storing images/videos in the db is not good practice, what is the better way to store these file types? The videos will linked in from YouTube (or another video provider).

Comment: If all you are doing is storing a link to YouTube, you will not need to store the video, and might not need to do much in order to support uploads, either. Before you start, take a look at available YouTube (or alternative) APIs, and see if they will fit with your app design. Open-ended  "what is best way to do this" questions are non-starters on Stack Overflow - if you are honestly at that stage, you are better off with a discussion forum, or doing more basic research on your own.

Comment: Thanks, I'll checkout the YouTube API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) Gem ([tutorial here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)).  Combine with a CDN, can be a good start for hosting images/videos.

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about Carrierwave!

Answer (score 0):

If you use external video services, then you will not keep video files in DB. You will only have links/ids of these videos.
So keeping it in database is usual practice.

If you are going to upload videos directly to your service, then you can use S3 to store them.

As eabraham said, carrierwave gem is simple and good solution for custom uploads, it also provides amazon S3 support.